# How to read xml file using Sax/Dom parser in Java?

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, domparser

I would like to ask you a problem. I want to read data from xml using either sax/dom parser but I don't know how to implement code in java. Any helps are highly appreciated...

Below texts about the requirements:

1/ xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElement>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM ORDERS]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ORDERID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="CUSTOMERID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="EMPLOYEEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="ORDERDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<field name="REQUIREDDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<field name="SHIPPEDDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<field name="SHIPVIA" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="FREIGHT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="SHIPNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPADDRESS" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPCITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPREGION" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPPOSTALCODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SHIPCOUNTRY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="da31a9d4-8ee7-481d-8b51-270539a2fdec" x="460" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[SHIPPEDDATE]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="60fb99da-64ef-4bf9-8a96-687c433be35a" x="460" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPPEDDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</rootElement>
```

2/ Expected Result:

```
element         : property
elment value    : null
attribute name  : name
attribute value : ireport.zoom 
attribute name  : value
attribute value : 1.0 

element         : property
elment value    : null
attribute name  : name
attribute value : ireport.x
attribute name  : value
attribute value : 0

element         : property
elment value    : null
attribute name  : name
attribute value : ireport.y
attribute name  : value
attribute value : 0

element         : queryString
elment value    : SELECT * FROM ORDERS
attribute name  : null
attribute value : null

element         : ORDERID
attribute name  : class
attribute value : java.lang.Integer
```

Any idea regarding to sax/dom parser technology using java program?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your xml file is not well-formed (rootElement is never closed). I guess that's a copy&paste error?

Comment: Did you try searching anywhere for something like "Java SAX example?"

Comment: @DavidEhrmann, I also tried to do so as well but it did not meet my requirements. If necessary, please refer to this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113529/how-to-get-elements-value-from-xml-using-sax-parser-in-startelement

Comment: Most XML parsers come with sample programs for both DOM and SAX. If yours didn't, try looking at [the Apache Xerces examples](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/samples.html)

Comment: If you want exactly this output in another file or an output stream you should investigate XSLT and FO, rather than hand-writing the transformation in Java. That way all you have to do is write general-purpose code, and the real work is done in your .xslt file.

Answer (score 2):

The [SAX example tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) pertaining to this topic is a pretty good start.

---

As seen in the [SAXParser Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html), one approach to parsing is to use a [DefaultHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html).

The three "events" you primarily care about and need to override are `startElement`, `endElement` and `characters`.

Inside of `startElement` you'll capture the `qName` (element) for the tag and it's associated [Attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html).

Inside of `characters` you'll capture the tag value (element value).

By the time the tag closes you'll have captured all of the required data that you desire. You can use the `endElement` to print / store that information.

---

You'd start with a `DefaultHandler` extension

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
     //Capture tag name and attributes
     super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);  
  }

  @Override
 public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
     //Capture value.  
     super.characters(ch, start, length);  
  }

  @Override
  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    //Print or store the information
  }
}
```

and provide the implementation for each event accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for helpful solution.
By the way, If I want all values like tagName, attributeName, attributeValue, and Element's Value store in one place, is it possible? I mean I need to the set of them for using with other thread.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You'd have to provide some data structure to store the information as you gathered it and index/hash it for later retrieval. Once the parsing was finished you would have a method on the handler to return the data.

Comment: I understand. But if necessary, can you drive me to that purpose?
Any samples are also appreciated.

Comment: Check out [this example](http://ideone.com/Z7t2mT). It's not exactly like you specified but close enough for you to see how it works and finish it up exactly like you want.