# How to return a set of object per node dynamically?

Tags: java, dom, domparser

Dear all valued members!!

I got some problem with read xml using DOM technology. I would like get a set of object per xml node/element. A set of object should contain like this: MyObject(String NodeName, String NodeValue, Map attributeMap). Is it possible to do that with DOM? Any suggestions are appreciated. Here is my example:

1/ xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001" adress="new york">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

2/ expected return result:

```
First set: 
   NodeName  = company
   NodeValue = null
   attributeMap = {null}
Second set: 
   NodeName  = staff
   NodeValue = null
   attributeMap = {id="1001",address="new york"}
Third Set:
   NodeName  = firstname
   NodeValue = yong
   attributeMap = {null}
Forth Set: 
   NodeName  = lastName
   NodeValue = mook kim
   attributeMap = {null}
And so on...
```

***Here is my Sample Code****

```
public ElementsContainer getElements(String filename) throws 
        ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

    Node tempNode;
    NamedNodeMap nodeMapAttributes;
    Node node;
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    ElementsContainer elements = null;


    File file = new File(filename);
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
    if(document.hasChildNodes()){
        for(int i=0; i<document.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
            tempNode = document.getChildNodes().item(i);
            if(tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                if(tempNode.getNodeValue()==null){
                   if(tempNode.hasAttributes()){
                       nodeMapAttributes = tempNode.getAttributes();
                       for(int k=0; k<nodeMapAttributes.getLength(); k++){
                           node = nodeMapAttributes.item(k);
                           attributes.put(node.getNodeName(), node.getNodeValue());
                       }
                   }
                   else{
                       attributes.put("", "");
                   }
                   elements = new ElementsContainer(tempNode.getNodeName(),tempNode.getNodeValue(),attributes);
                }
                else{
                    if(tempNode.hasAttributes()){
                       nodeMapAttributes = tempNode.getAttributes();
                       for(int k=0; k<nodeMapAttributes.getLength(); k++){
                           node = nodeMapAttributes.item(k);
                           attributes.put(node.getNodeName(), node.getNodeValue());
                       }
                   }
                   else{
                       attributes.put("", "");
                   }
                   elements = new ElementsContainer(tempNode.getNodeName(),tempNode.getNodeValue(),attributes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Two problems: 1) You never process more than one `Node` level deep. 2) You will never store more that one Node

Comment: As I think, the second problem can be solve by using List as the return type. The problem is how can we access one node and get set of object as mentioned above at once. Then we can add this object to List.

Comment: If you're going to build your own data structure rather than using the DOM as your document model, you might want to consider using a SAX parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious as to why a similar approach to that I provided in [your similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112813/how-to-read-xml-file-using-sax-dom-parser-in-java/24113674#comment37200982_24113674) wasn't used.

Nevertheless, the two issues you have to address in your current approach

- the  nodes are nested and a single pass isn't sufficient
- capture each `Node` in some type of [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).
- as a 3rd point of interest to address, get rid of as much of that `if-else` as possible

Once approach is to traverse the `Document` recursively:

```
private void processNodes(final NodeList list, 
                          final ElementContainer parent, 
                          final List<ElementContainer> elements){

  for(int i=0; i< list.getLength(); i++){
      final Node node = list.item(i);
       if("#text".equals(node.getNodeName())){
         parent.setValue(node.getNodeValue());
       }
       else{
         final ElementContainer p =  processNode(node, elements);
         processNodes(node.getChildNodes(), p, elements);
       }
  }
}
```

To capture each node:

```
private ElementContainer processNode(Node node, List<ElementContainer> elements){
  final ElementContainer element = new ElementContainer(node.getNodeName(), node.getNodeValue());

 if(node.hasAttributes()){
   final NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();
   for(int k=0; k<attrs.getLength(); k++){
     final Node attr = attrs.item(k);
     element.addAttribute(attr.getNodeName(), attr.getNodeValue());
   }
  }
  elements.add(element);
  return element;
}
```

Check out [my example](http://ideone.com/718KWs)

Comment: Thanks you for helpful solution and patient. I made it work. But one more thing I would like to know. "<text><![CDATA[SHIPPEDDATE]]></text>" is call CDATA node type, right. Regarding to your above code, I applied other xml file, but it does not show value of "<![CDATA[SHIPPEDDATE]]>". Please help

Comment: Update your sample XML to include that field.

Comment: _Here is another xml sample file:_

`<page><columnHeader><band height="20" splitType="Stretch"><text><![CDATA[HEADER]]></text></band></columnHeader><detail><band height="20" splitType="Stretch"><textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{VALUES}]]></textFieldExpression></band></detail><footer><band height="20" splitType="Stretch"><text><![CDATA[FOOTER]]></text></band></footer></page>`

Comment: It is a [CDATA_SECTION_NODE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#CDATA_SECTION_NODE). What was the code you used to check the type?

Comment: This is the CDATA_SECTION_NODE, as I thought, but I didn't use code to check. However, this the code we can use to print node type 
`node.getNodeType()`

Comment: In order for the data to show up based on my code you would have to check for that type and assign it to `parent`'s value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55542/discussion-between-origineil-and-sakura).